# A “Before And After” Image Comparison Slide Control in Android

Tags: android, photo

Is there a possibility to build a image comparison slide control in Android as one that exists in HTML 5?

http://thenewcode.com/819/A-Before-And-After-Image-Comparison-Slide-Control-in-HTML5

How can I achieve this thing?

Comment: It appears you just need to change the Alpha value of an image upon a Slider value change.

Comment: It seems you should have 2 bitmaps (before and after). I would create a custom view that holds/handle these 2 bitmaps and draw them accordingly using `drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)`.

Answer (score 10):

I have created [library](https://github.com/developer--/before_after_slider/blob/master/README.md) for this functionality, may be someone who steel need this feature,it will be good for them.

```
compile 'com.github.developer--:beforeafterslider:1.0.4'
```

Comment: Jemo, great job! I tried to use your slider, it's really great. I found one bug though - when I set the same image for both parts of the slider (the before and after) it seems that one of the images becomes distorted, like it's slightly zoomed (sorry to write here, I don't have a Github account).

Comment: It's the line
val tmpBitmap = getScaledBitmap(theBitmap)
in ClipDrawableProcessorTask.kt  Probably, you put it there in order to show that the images are different, when one sets both parts of the slider to the same image. So I commented it and now it all works fine. The "before" image is on the right, the "after" is on the left. Again, thanks for your work, really helped me a lot to demonstrate some image processing effects.

Answer (score 6):

One way is using a seekbar and a framelayout that sits on top of the original Image. As you slide the seekbar the frames height adjusts which contains the 2nd image.

**Code for top down reveal**

```
    private SeekBar seekBar;
```

under `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

add

```
seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            int progress = 0;

            @Override

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                FrameLayout target = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.target);

                progress = progresValue;

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = target.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height = progress;
                target.setLayoutParams(lp);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

**the layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pug_color"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/target"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageb"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/pug_bw"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="300"
        android:max="600" />
</RelativeLayout>
```